# subtract variable number of days from timestamp in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I know the following can be done in db2:

```
select * from table where created_date < current_timestamp - 5 days;
```

but what is the correct syntax to do something like the following?

```
begin
    declare numdays int default 5;

    -- some logic

    select * from table where created_date < current_timestamp - numdays days;
end;
```

Comment: Looks like the syntax I used for an example is actually the correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables can be directly used in place of a constant as seen below:

```
create table test (dt timestamp);

begin
    declare numdays int;
    set numdays = 10;
    insert into test
    SELECT CURRENT_timestamp + numdays DAYS FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
end ;

select current_timestamp, dt from test;
```

Returns

```
 2017-12-14 08:20:39.19063 2017-12-24 08:20:35.503779
```